# Laravel 5 AJAX Sort Order data (jQuery Sortable) with no HTML form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm to trying to store a sort order to each article within a help centre for my new site using Laravel 5 and having a bit of trouble getting it to work. I'm using jQuery UI's `.sortable` for arranging the elements on the page, and since there are going to be multiple sections throughout the site where areas are sortable, my jQuery script is built in a way for a 'one script for all' purposes. Hence the use of `data-*` attributes and route name references.

Here is the code I've got so far:

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('admin/help-centre/category/{category_id}/section/{section_id}/article/sort-order', 'AdminHelpCentreArticleController@sortOrder');
```

**AdminHelpCentreArticleController.php**

```
public function sortOrder($category_id, $section_id)
{
    /* Return ------------------------------------- */
        return [
            'category_id' => $category_id,
            'section_id' => $section_id
        ];
}
```

**show.blade.php (Admin Article Listing)**

```
<ul id="help-center-articles-sort" class="sortable">
    @foreach ($helpCentreArticles as $helpCentreArticle)
        <li class="sortable-element" data-sortable-element-id="{{ $helpCentreArticle->id }}">
            <a href="{{ action('AdminHelpCentreArticleController@show', array($helpCentreCategory->id, $helpCentreSection->id, $helpCentreArticle->id)) }}" target="_self">{{ $helpCentreArticle->title }}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<a href="{{ $helpCentreSection->id }}/article/sort-order" target="_self" class="button bm-remove w-full sortable-save" data-sortable-id="help-center-articles-sort">Save Order</a>
```

**scripts.js (includes CSRF Token `_token`)**

```
var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (options.type.toLowerCase() === 'post')
    {
        options.data += options.data?'&':''; // add leading ampersand if `data` is non-empty
        options.data += '_token=' + csrfToken; // add _token entry
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sortable').sortable();

    $('.sortable-save').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var route = $(this).attr('href'),
            sortableID = $(this).attr('data-sortable-id');

        var data = $('#' + sortableID + ' .sortable-element').map(function() { 
            return $(this).attr('data-sortable-element-id');
        }).get();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: route,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id_array: data },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Everything so far is working in terms of the return response in the console, which is `Object {category_id: "1", section_id: "1"}`. But no matter what I try, I cannot seem to pass through the `data` map to the controller to use it.

I've tried a bunch of guesswork since I cannot find a single decent tutorial on AJAX in Laravel 5 anywhere, and I've tried things such as adding a `$data` parameter to the `sortOrder()` method, I've tried `Input::all()` and `Request::all` but it all returns errors (I'm guessing cause it's not an actual form?).

Once I've got the data to be passed through to the controller I'll be able to save the sort order to the database easily enough. But I can't quite get to that stage, any ideas?

**EDIT**

I should probably note that I do have a `HelpCentreArticle` model and a `HelpCentreArticleRequest` request too, here's some of the code from each file in case they are also needed:

**HelpCentreArticle.php**

```
class HelpCentreArticle extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'section_id',
        'title',
        'content',
        'excerpt',
        'is_visible',
        'sort_order',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by',
    ];
}
```

**HelpCentreArticleRequest.php**

```
class HelpCentreArticleRequest extends Request {        

    /* Authorization ------------------------------ */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }


    /* Validation rules --------------------------- */
        public function rules()
        {
            $rules = [
                'title' => 'required|min:3',
                'content' => 'required|min:10',
            ];

            return $rules;
        }

}
```

I wasn't sure if I needed to add `HelpCentreSectionRequest $request` as the last parameter of the `sortOrder()` method, so I could use `$request->all()` but it just returns a `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` in the console log.

Comment: what `$_POST['id_array']` prints?

Comment: @itachi I did end up using $_POST to fetch the array, and it seems to be working, it just doesn't seem like the correct approach to use for the Laravel framework, since you usual use request/response/input to obtain post data in Laravel.

Comment: There is too much code your question that are not needed. I guess the question is, you're trying to send the data-* values using ajax post but you're not receiving it ?  you're sending the data  as  id_array: data in y our controller the data array could be retrieved as Input::get('id_array')

Comment: I don't particularly see how it's too much code, covering every aspect I think is good logic. But that aside, using `Input::get();` was the correct way, as I tried previously, except I wasn't include `use Input;` in the controller. I've added this as an answer. Thanks for your replies, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it appears that the correct way was to use `Input::get('id_array');` instead of `$_POST['id_array'];`, which I tried, but when I originally tried this I wasn't including `use Input;` at the top of my controller, as I thought this was already accessible, but it wasn't.

Adding `use Input;`, and using `Input::get();` is now working as expected.

Here is the updated code:

**AdminHelpCentreArticleController.php**

```
public function sortOrder($category_id, $section_id)
{

    /* Query Select ------------------------------- */
        $helpCentreCategory = HelpCentreCategory::findOrFail($category_id);
        $helpCentreSection = HelpCentreSection::findOrFail($section_id);


    /* Variables ---------------------------------- */
        $id_array = Input::get('id_array');
        $sort_order = 1;


    /* Query Update ------------------------------- */
        foreach($id_array as $id) {
            $helpCentreArticle = HelpCentreArticle::where('id', $id)->first();

            $helpCentreArticle->sort_order = $sort_order;
            $helpCentreArticle->save();

            $sort_order++;
        }


    /* Return ------------------------------------- */
        return ['success' => true];

}
```

Then you can obviously access `success` for an `if else` statement in your jQuery to manipulate the page.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of UI sortable with Laravel

**index.blade.php**

```
...
@foreach($photos as $photo)
<tr data-sortable="{{ $photo->pivot->position }}" data-id="{{ $restaurant->id }}" data-photo-id="{{ $photo->pivot->photo_id }}">
    <td>
        <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </td>
...
</tr>
@endforeach
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#sortable-ui tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelper,
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $("#sortable-ui tbody tr").each(function(index){
            console.log($(this).data('id')+', '+(index+1));
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route('owner.photo.update.position') }}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'restaurant_id='+$(this).data('id')+'&photo_id='+$(this).data('photo-id')+'&position='+(index+1)
            })
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXhr) {
                console.log(jqXhr);
            });
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();
</script>
```

**scripts.js**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

**AjaxController.php**

```
public function updatePhotoPosition(Request $request)
{
    $restaurant = $this->restaurantRepository->getById($request->get('restaurant_id'));
    $photoId = $request->get('photo_id');
    $photo = $restaurant
        ->photos()
        ->wherePivot('photo_id', $photoId)
        ->first();

    $photo->pivot->position = $request->get('position');
    $photo->pivot->save();
}
```